# Sticky Footer using css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set a div stay at the bottom of the browser screen even when scrolling?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=sticky+footer+using+css

Comment: @Pranav I see your Google search and raise you a site search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sticky+footer+css 759 questions. A dupe of a dupe of a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS, sticky footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465250/css-sticky-footer), [Sticky Footer CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822825/sticky-footer-css), and the dozens of questions linked from these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position: fixed` property of the CSS attached to that `div`.

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Say you have the following div

`<div class="footer">This is at the bottom</div>`

you can make it stick at the bottom of the viewport with the following CSS

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

It will stay there even when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try at this CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

CSS source: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of sticky footer

Please have a look

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent footer tutorial at

http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/

The demo page is here:

http://www.lwis.net/profile/CSS/sticky-footer.html

The basic premise is that the main body page is stretched to a 100% of the page. With a min-height of 100% too.

The footer is then given the following rules:

```
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
```

I got answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height)